# Let $T\in Mat_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}), X\in Mat_{n\times p}(\mathbb{R})$. Given the subspace $S=\{X|TX=0\}$, Find $dimS$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Let $T\in Mat_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}), X\in Mat_{n\times p}(\mathbb{R})$.

Given the subspace $S =\{X \ |T X=0 \}$, Find the dimension of $S$.

***My attempt:*** 
Actually, I have tried that for any column $C_i$ of $X$, $C_i \in Null(A)$, and corresponding to every vector $C_i \in Null(A)$, there exists an $ X \in Mat_{n\times p}$ such that $X \in S$.
   And, the dimension of $S \leq np$, but how to find it ???

Let $T\in Mat_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}), X\in Mat_{n\times p}(\mathbb{R})$.Given the subspace $S=\{X|TX=0\}$, Find $dimS$

Comment: You know that the answer depends upon $T$, right?!

Comment: Yes, Sir !!! Let rank T = r, then how to approach ???

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, Sir, can you please provide me a hint so that I can approach ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\ker T=n-r$, where $r=\operatorname{rank}T$. Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\{v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $\ker T$. Then a matrix $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$ belongs to $S$ if and only if, for each $w\in\mathbb R^p$, $X.w\in\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n\}\bigr)$. It is not hard to deduce from this that $\dim S=(n-r)\times p$.

Comment: Sir, in the iff statement of your answer, how Xw € Ker T inplies that TX=0 ???

Comment: Because\begin{align}(\forall w\in\mathbb R^p):X.w\in\ker T&\iff(\forall w\in\mathbb R^p):T.(X.v)=0\\&\iff(\forall w\in\mathbb R^p):(T.X).v=0\\&\iff T.X=0.\end{align}

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Respected sir, I cannot understand the part how you deduced dim S. can you please explain it a little briefly. Thank you

Comment: Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_p\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^p$. Then, if $X\in S$, $X.e_1$ must. be of the form $\alpha_{1,1}v_{r+1}+\alpha_{2,1}v_{r+2}+\cdots\alpha_{n-r,1}v_r$. And $X.e_2$ must. be of the form $\alpha_{1,2}v_{r+1}+\alpha_{2,2}v_{r+2}+\cdots\alpha_{n-r,2}v_r$. And so $n$. How many $\alpha$'s are here? The answer is $(n-r)\times p$.